# Reducing unnecessary work for a multiple-instance service

Tags: architecture, message-queue, microservices, distributed-system

I have a little service which connects to a third party web-service, obtains some information and saves it into a mongo collection. The data this service is interested in is pretty static, but it it can change under exceptional circumstances (it is football schedules, btw). To get notified about changes, the service checks back every 3-6 hours to see if any matches have been cancelled or rescheduled. New entries end up in the database, old ones are discarded (since they are already in the collection).

The service also exposes a GET endpoint, to which users connect.

Now, this is fine when I run a single instance of the service, but not so nice when I have multiple instances (probably it does not make sense for all instances to query the data service every three hours and discard most of the result).

I have the following ideas how to solve this:

- Use some kind of leader election algorithm, only the leader should query the third party service
- Separate the service into two: one smaller service would query the data (still problematic with several instances), put the result on a message queue so it's guaranteed that only one consumer takes and processes that result
- Combine the first two ideas: leader election for the querying service, message queues for consuming data
- Use some kind of distributed lock (I am aware of a solution with Redis/Jedis) so only one service does the querying. This, however feels a bit of an overkill; adding Redis just for locking is like...meh...
- A much better, other idea, commonly used in such cases :-)

Could you please let me know if there is a preferred solution to such problems?

Comment: Why do you need many instances checking the same data? just for redundancy?

Comment: Since the service also has that GET endpoint, I want this to be highly available. I don't really want single points of failure in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep things easy and avoid overcomplexity.
Just persist the WS response time and each instance before  calling again the WS, should check on DB how much time passed since last call.

Comment: But when the timestamp expires, I believe only one of the instance should be allowed to update this timestamp. Otherwise, each arriving request will notice that the timestamp is expired and will require a new update.

Comment: When a "grace period" for a time stamp is expired and an instance requests again the data from the WS it will persist the new data with the new timestamp, so the other instances checking for the time stamp will find a valid timestamp.

Comment: Yes, but if there are more than one requests received in the time interval [t1, t2]  (where t1 is the beginning of an update request, and t2 is when update is finalised) when the timestamp is updated, other instances besides the first one can also make the request (after t1 and before t2). Also, if the instance updates the timestamp and then makes the request, then it should be some sort of blocking of the blocking done on reading/writing the value of the timestamp. This will ensure that only one instance reads the value. Then, the instance can update the timestamp, and make the request to WS

Comment: I think that in this particular case a double WS call in the scenary you described doesn't cause any negative issue and it waste of resources is statistically very limited.
As you stated it may be anyhow solved  locking the table reading whiole updating: anyhow this behaviour causes much more consequences than a double call.

Comment: Yes, but each API call has a cost, whether it is a price per API call or only the latency introduced by this call. The OP didn't mention whether there is payment involved when using the WS